# migration HP-UX to Hyper-V

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hp-ux

I would like to ask about possibility to migrate  phisically server (HP RP3440) with installed HP-UX v11.1 to Hyper-V/VirtualBox/VMware.

Thanks for Your effort to explain me how to do it.

Comment: Try using P2V converters, for Hyper-V https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd, for VMware https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html

Answer (score 3):

The [RP3440](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04283185.pdf) appears to have an PA-8x00 processor. This can't be virtualized with either product, as they are all limited to 32/64 bit Intel architectures.